# Read a number. Find product after deleting last and second last digit

Tags: r

For example: Input: 4358, output: 190530 (438*435)
I cannot find the answer
I tried extracting but that is not working

Answer (score 2):

You can use the operators `%%` and `%/%` to remove numbers at specific positions in integer values.

```
x <- 4358
x %/% 10 * ((x %/% 100) * 10 + x %% 10)
#[1] 190530
```